# Assigning value to a workflow or worklet variable

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a worklet variable which needs to be assigned with the value from the parameter file of the workflow, is it possible to do it in informatica power centre 9.1?

Please let me know how to implement this, don’t have any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the worklet and look for `Variables` tab. There you can manage pre-worklet and post-worklet variable assignment, as described in the [documentation](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/advanced-workflow-guide/workflow-variables/assigning-variable-values-in-a-worklet/configuring-variable-assignments.html).

Comment: qn - can we modify them using parameter file?

Comment: Sure. You can assigna a value directly in parameter file: https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-5/advanced-workflow-guide/parameter-files/parameter-file-structure/parameter-file-sections.html#:~:text=You%20can%20define%20parameters%20and,process%20that%20runs%20the%20task. The question was about passing the value from workflow parameter, as I understood.